# How to force Xcode to use Proxy Settings for source control?

Tags: xcode, http-proxy, xcode13.3

My mac at work requires a proxy to access the web. I have managed to use `git global http` to define proxy settings and it work just fine through the terminal.

However, It does not seem to work when using Xcode `source control` feature. Xcode version `13.3`

[image: Currently using the Git option presented here.]

I am getting the following error `Failed to Connect` - Please note that I am able to use the terminal and do a `git clone` just fine.

[image: Error]

Is there any other setting that needs to be set for xcode to recognize the proxy settings?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use the defualt proxy used in System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies in XCode V 13.4.1 by Editing the following file. Quit xcode if running and edit

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/java/conf/net.properties

and set the following property to true ( false by default )

```
java.net.useSystemProxies=true
```